# How can I set default headers for all requests?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a lot of requests. How can I set default headers for all requests? Please, give me examples

Now My code look like this:

```
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity params = null;
    try {
        params = new StringEntity(o.writeValueAsString(auth));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);
    try {
        client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So I have many requests like this

Comment: What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using the `HttpClientBuilder`, why not try using its [setDefaultHeaders()](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#setDefaultHeaders(java.util.Collection)) method?

```
HttpClientBuilder client = HttpClientBuilder.create();
Header header = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");    
client.setDefaultHeaders(header);    
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity params = null;
try {
    params = new StringEntity(o.writeValueAsString(auth));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
request.setEntity(params);
try {
    client.build();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);  
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The most awkward are the try-catches. Best would be to throw them to the caller, and rely on the logging there.

However a single try-catch is possible too. There the style `declaration of var + try{ assigning to var } processing var` should better be `try { declaration + assigning + processing` }

Then one already gets shorter, more readable code.

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
try {
    request.setEntity(new StringEntity(o.writeValueAsString(auth)));
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);  
} catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e);
}
```

The HttpClient part is still a bit dubious, and could be reduced without declaration.

Alternatives exist like using annotations, Spring and some more declarative techniques. But this is short enough.